# Push fields if record is matching in group aggregation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, grouping

I have these `"$group"` parameters in the aggregation query :

```js
{
 _id: {
    user_uuid: "$actor.user.uuid",

    date_string: {
        $dateToString: {
            format: "%Y-%m-%d",
            date: {
                $toDate: "$time",
            },
            timezone: "America/New_York",
        },
    },
    
  },
  
  exit_time: {$max: "$time"},
  entry_time: {$min: "$time"},

  records: {
      $push: {
          time: "$time",
          user_name: "$actor.user.name",
          email: "$actor.user.email",
          door:"$door.name",
          //entry_door:{$cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$entry_time", "$time" ] }, then: "$door.name", else: "$$REMOVE" }},
          //exit_door:{$cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$exit_time", "$time" ] }, then: "$door.name", else: "$$REMOVE" }},
 
      },
  }
            
}
```

and this is my sample document :

```json
{

  "time": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1654061180000"
    }
  },
 
  "actor": {
    "type": "USER",
    "user": {
      "uuid": "6fff0a80-8409-4008-9850-9ec8fb8431ee",
      "name": "firstname lastname",
      "email": "firstname.lastname@example.com",
      "department": "Sales",
      "employee_number": null,
      "cost_center": "USA",
      "role": "ADMIN",
      
    }
  },
  
  "door": {
    "uuid": "42ac456e-df9b-4146-afb7-619dd584a524",
    "name": "Door Plaza Parking entry 2",
    "is_elevator_door": false,
    "elevator_door_type": null,
    "is_door_force_masked": true,
    "is_door_held_masked": true,
    "is_door_force_seen": false,
    "is_temperature_screening": false
  },

}
```

For your understanding this is related to access control. We need to track the attendance according to who is coming and going from the `door` so for that particular user on that date if user is making first entrance from the `door` then this is entry time and last exit is exit time.

I am first matching the records and then grouping it as per above query. I want the data of the users on that particular date to track the attendance after calculating the entry and exit time. Till here I am on track and query is fine but with this I also want which is the door from which user entered and which one is the door from which the user took exit because a lot of doors are there but we need to take only entry and exit door.

I was trying the method like at the time of calculating the max and min time I can store the door information at that time but I am not able to figure out what to do. I have commented out the entry and exit door condition because it is not correct.

Please help me out in this.

Let me know if more details are required.

Thanks

Comment: If you `"$sort"` by `"time"` before the `"$group"`, are the `"door"` records you are looking for the `"$first"` and `"$last"`?  BTW, I'm wondering if this logic would work for users who work past midnight, etc.

Comment: Yes I am sorting by date_string and records.user_name after group but whole timestamp is not there so that we can get the first and last document. And regarding the time I am first converting it into different timezone while grouping. I am grouping on particular date and userid so that I will have all the data of that user on that particular date.